# How to listen to an observable list?

Tags: flutter, dart, observable

I want to use an [`ObservableList`](https://pub.dev/documentation/observable/latest/observable/ObservableList-class.html) as a way to listen to changes to a single value. Here's what I've tried:

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
name: observable_demo

dependencies:
  observable: ^0.24.0
```

Dart script:

```dart
import 'package:observable/observable.dart';

void main() {
  var obs = ObservableList.from(["first value"]);
  obs.changes.listen(([value = ""]) {
    print(value);
  });
  obs[0] = "second valuee";
}
```

I run it with `dart run demo.dart` and it prints nothing. I'd like it to print:

```
second valuee
```

`obs.changes` is a [`Stream<List<String>>`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-async/Stream-class.html):

- [`Observable.changes`](https://pub.dev/documentation/observable/latest/observable/Observable/changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an `ObservableList`, you should be using the [`listChanges`](https://pub.dev/documentation/observable/latest/observable/ObservableList/listChanges.html) stream instead.