# How to share app-wide mutable data in Flutter widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to share application-wide data across the state of all widgets in an app? For example, let's say an `username` that changes in response to an update in the user profile, causing widgets to be rebuilt.

I've read that using [`InheritedWidget`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) can easily achieve this, which looks like:

```dart
UserDataWidget.of(buildContext).username
```

However, it's a convention that all instance variables in a widget be `final`, or read-only. And anyway, it'd make sense to use an observable if you need an instance variable that can change. So I wanted something like that inside the above example widget, `UserDataWidget`:

```dart
final ObservableList<String> username = ObservableList.from(['initial-username']);
```

However this `ObservableList` from the `observable` package in pub.dev [doesn't work: changes aren't listened to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76733950/19692949).

What can I do then?

---

A friend referenced [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) from pub.dev: can it be used safely as a `final var` inside a `InheritedWidget`, without needing to listen to changes in a callback?

Comment: Welcome to the world of state-management. The most popular is riverpod.

Comment: @RichardHeap This looks what I'm looking for, but where comes `ConsumerWidget` from? Nowhere in API docs.

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/ConsumerWidget-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best combination is the *GetIt* package for singletons and the *flutter_bloc* package for the direct state management (but of course there are other opinions to use *riverprod*, or *GetX*).

You could also manage everything directly with inherited widgets, but it's a bit more complicated for larger apps.

The recommended approach by Flutter is to use the **provider** package which is a wrapper around inherited widgets.

Most of the times you use some `ChangeNotifier` **model** that you provide in some parent Widget higher up the widget tree and the children can then access this **model** and call methods on it to change it inside of button *onPressed* callbacks, etc.
Those methods inside of the model then need to call `notifyListeners` if they change some data so that all listeners(the widgets that depend on it) rebuild with the new data.

You access the model with `Provider.of<SomeModel>(context, listen: true)` (or a `Consumer` widget) inside of the build method of the children to listen for changes, but inside of callbacks where you only want to change data of the model, you use `listen: false`.

This is a short provider example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// this small example shows how everything works the same with provider

class ProviderParent extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ProviderParent(this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeModel>(
      create: (BuildContext context) {
        return SomeModel(5);
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class ProviderChild extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProviderChild({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProviderChild> createState() => _ProviderChildState();
}

class _ProviderChildState extends State<ProviderChild> {
  late final SomeModel providedModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    providedModel = Provider.of<SomeModel>(context, listen: false); // of course you can already access the parent
    // provider inside of the initstate method and also cache the change notifier model (but of course you could not
    // use the cached member variable for the build method without listening to the providers notifications)
    /// providedModel.add(10); // JUST REMEBER TO NOT MODIFY THE CHANGE NOTIFIER INSIDE OF THE INIT STATE (because
    /// this will be executing during the building of the widget tree and you cannot modify a change notifier during
    /// this). USE A POST FRAME CALLBACK FOR THIS!!!
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this listens to the provider with a consumer widget, but also directly with the provider.of with listen true.
    // and it modifies the change notifier to send new modifications with either the cached model, or using provider
    // .of with listen=false
    return Consumer<SomeModel>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, SomeModel someModel, Widget? child) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("From consumer: ${someModel.someData}"),
            Text("From build: ${Provider.of<SomeModel>(context, listen: true).someData}"),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => providedModel.someData += 10, child: const Text("Change with cached")),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Provider.of<SomeModel>(context, listen: false).someData += 20,
              child: const Text("Change with fresh"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class SomeModel with ChangeNotifier {
  int _someData; // change notifier with some mutable data that is wrapped with getter + setter

  SomeModel([int initialData = 100]) : _someData = initialData;

  int get someData => _someData;

  set someData(int data) {
    _someData = data;
    notifyListeners(); // update all listeners when members change!
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: ProviderParent(ProviderChild()),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: I found [`riverpod`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/) more concise compared to `provider`, but it's less popular than `provider` (98% vs 100%)

Comment: Yeah, riverpod is also loved by many. There is no "wrong" choice here. Just choose what you are most comfortable with. The two are also a bit similar and are made by the same guy.